scalable csv file reader source in flink
I'm trying to create a csvFileReader in flink that can be scalable (i.e. increase the parallelism) yet maintain the order. I'm not sure if my issue lies with not being able to create a correct watermarkstrategy or if I'm not using the correct type of function.
currently, my only implementation is as follows:
this.watermarkStrategy = WatermarkStrategy
                .<EventBasic>forMonotonousTimestamps()
                .withTimestampAssigner((element, recordTimestamp) -> element.value.timeStamp);
.
.
.
DataStream<EventBasic> mainStream = env.readFile(  new TextInputFormat(new Path(csvFilePath)), csvFilePath, FileProcessingMode.PROCESS_ONCE, 1000)
                .setParallelism(1)
                .flatMap(new CSVSourceFlatMapParallelized())
                .setParallelism(1)
                .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(watermarkStrategy).name("source");



This has its shortcomings since once I try to increase the parallelism the order is no longer maintained. I need the order to be maintained, since in the csv file the the timestamp is given and the process functions (that have their own custom windowing) need these timestamps/events to arrive in order. Since they won't know when to flush out the window.
e.g. of csv file input:
key,val,timestamp
E,0,500
F,1,500
Y,2,500
Z,3,500
F,4,500


for more context this is how my custom windowing works :
long currentTime;
    long endWindowTime;
    long windowTime; //in ms
    long startWindowTime;
    //sum + count for each key
    private volatile HashMap<String, Tuple2<Integer, Integer>> SumCountMap;

@Override
    public void processElement(EventBasic event, Context ctx, Collector<EventBasic> out) throws Exception {
        String key = event.key;


        if(event.value.timeStamp > endWindowTime){
            printMapState();
            outputMaxValues(out);
            startWindowTime = endWindowTime;
            endWindowTime += windowTime;
            currentTime = event.value.timeStamp;
        }

        if(event.value.timeStamp < startWindowTime){
            System.out.println("not working");
        }

        // If no maximum value has been stored yet or the incoming value is greater, update the MapState

        if(!SumCountMap.containsKey(key)){
            SumCountMap.put(key, new Tuple2<>(event.value.valueInt , 1));
        }
        else{
            Tuple2<Integer, Integer> curr = SumCountMap.get(key);
            SumCountMap.put(key, new Tuple2<>(curr.f0 + event.value.valueInt , curr.f1 + 1));
        }


    }


I have also tried the following :
DataStream<EventBasic> mainStream = env.addSource(new CsvEventBasicSourceFunction(csvFilePath))
                .setParallelism(3)
                .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(watermarkStrategy).name("source");

but this did not work since I needed my env to be set to BATCH mode.
